# C# pass element of value type array by reference

Tags: c#

I'd like to pass an element of an array (array contains value type elements, not ref type) by reference.

Is this possible?  Thank you

Comment: you can pass the array element using `ref` keyword.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, that's absolutely possible, in exactly the same way as you pass any other variable by reference:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] values = new int[10];
        Foo(ref values[0]);
        Console.WriteLine(values[0]); // 10
    }

    static void Foo(ref int x)
    {
        x = 10;
    }
}
```

This works because arrays are treated as "collections of variables" so `values[0]` is classified as a variable - you wouldn't be able to do a `List<int>`, where `list[0]` would be classified as a *value*.

Answer (score 7):

As an addition to Jon's answer, from C# 7 you can now do this kind of thing inline without the need for a wrapping method, with a "ref local". Note the need for the double usage of the "ref" keyword in the syntax.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] values = new int[10];
        ref var localRef = ref values[0];
        localRef = 10;
        //... other stuff
        localRef = 20;

        Console.WriteLine(values[0]); // 20
    }
```

This can be useful for situations where you need to refer to or update the same position in an array many times in a single method. It helps me to to avoid typos, and naming the variable stops me forgetting what array[x] refers to.

Links:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-ref-returns-and-ref-local-in-c-sharp-7-0/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns