# How to implement something like int*[] in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, c

In C/C++, the type of array element can be int*. Can C# implement something like it?
For example:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    int* a1[2];
    a1[0] = &x;
    a1[1] = &y;
    *a1[0] = 3;
    *a1[1] = 4;
    printf("%d\n", x);
    printf("%d\n", y);
}
```

Comment: Are you asking out of intellectual curiosity, or do you have a specific problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Read about [Arrays in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/)

Comment: Don't try to apply semantics from one language to another, languages can/will have totally different semantics for seemingly similar syntax. In this case C# has a different way of handling memory then C++ (or C) does. C/C++ have pointers and memory is (explicitly) managed by the programmer. While in C# everything is a reference and memory is managed using garbage collection.  So really study C#'s memory management model first.

Comment: Exactly like that? no. But you can do the opposite and define a local variable that contains a reference to an array element. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108060/c-sharp-pass-element-of-value-type-array-by-reference

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest you are going to get to this code

```
static class Program
{
    unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 1;
        int y = 2;

        var a1 = stackalloc int*[2];
        a1[0] = &x;
        a1[1] = &y;
        
        *a1[0] = 3;
        *a1[1] = 4;

        Console.WriteLine("{0}", x);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int* a1[2];
> ...
> *a1[0] = 3;
> *a1[1] = 4;
> ```

This is more or less equal to the following C# code:

```
int[][] a1 = new int[2][];
...
a1[0][0] = 3;
a1[1][0] = 4;
```

> ```
> int x = 1;
> int y = 2;
> ...
> a1[0] = &x;
> a1[1] = &y;
> ```

If you want to use "pure .NET code" (not `unsafe` etc.), you might simulate a primitive variable using an array with a size of `[1]`. I often used that method when programming in Java (for example to simulate `out` or `ref` parameters that exist in C# but not in Java):

```
int[] x = new int[] { 1 }; // instead of int x = 1;
int[] y = new int[] { 2 }; // instead of int y = 2;
...
a1[0] = x;
a1[1] = y;
```

If you do this, you have to replace all occurrences of `x` by `x[0]`, of course:

```
Console.WriteLine("x = " + x[0]); // instead of Console.WriteLine("x = " + x);
```